# quarkus reactive named data source em is null

Tags: hibernate, vert.x, quarkus, quarkus-panache, mutiny

So,

My Quarkus project (v2.2.2) has the following core features:

- reactive postgresql database with mutiny
- h2 database for the tests that do not mock repositories

When writing the tests I was getting an error during quarkus startup (forgot what that error was) however some page had recommended to swap over to named datasources to avoid the issue. This at the time seemed to have worked and my mocked-repository tests passed.

Fast forward a bit and I tried doing a test that uses the database. I am now getting this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.reactive.mutiny.Mutiny$Session.createQuery(String)" because "em" is null
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.common.runtime.CommonPanacheQueryImpl.createBaseQuery(CommonPanacheQueryImpl.java:307)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.common.runtime.CommonPanacheQueryImpl.createQuery(CommonPanacheQueryImpl.java:255)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.common.runtime.CommonPanacheQueryImpl.lambda$list$6(CommonPanacheQueryImpl.java:221)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualFunction.apply(SlowContextualFunction.java:21)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:68)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:57)
```

my application.yml  (with `customers` being the named datasource) :

```
quarkus:
  datasource:
    customers:
      db-kind: h2
      jdbc: false
      reactive:
        url: h2:file:~/testdb
        max-size: 20
```

My test:

```
@QuarkusTest
public class CustomerControllerTest {

  private static final String BASE_URL = "/my-url";

  @Test
  public void testBasicCreation() {
    final Response response = given()
        .when()
        .body("{\"a\":3}")
        .post(BASE_URL)
        .then()
        .extract().response();
    assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode(), () -> "Got: " + response.prettyPrint());
    assertEquals("", response.getBody().as(String.class));
  }
}
```

My controller's first step is to use this repository:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyCustRepo implements io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.PanacheRepository<MyCust> {
}
```

and my entity:

```
@Entity(name = "cust_entries")
@Data
@PersistenceUnit("customers")
public class MyCust {

  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  Long id;
  @Column(name = "val")
  Boolean val;
}
```

From what I had found the `@persistenceUnit` on the entity object was supposed to associate the appropriate datasource. However it seems like Mutiny$Session is null. am I missing something?

---

Update 1

on Quarkus v 2.3.0 CR1

```
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>0.2.0</lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.0.Beta1</org.mapstruct.version>
    <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.20</org.projectlombok.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.3.0.CR1</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
```

Full dependency tree here: https://www.codepile.net/pile/8jQeJ3j2

Scenario 1: Default data source (no PersistenceUnit annotations and application.yaml has no name for the data source)

On running test i get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No pool has been defined for persistence unit default-reactive
```

Scenario 2: If i set it to use the named data sources, I get:

```
my.project.customer.conrtoller.CustomerControllerTest.testBasicCreation  Time elapsed: 2.12 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Got: {
    "details": "Error id 083dd288-ddff-463b-bfd1-dafdbbf13c98-1, java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"org.hibernate.reactive.mutiny.Mutiny$Session.createQuery(String)\" because \"em\" is null",
    "stack": "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"org.hibernate.reactive.mutiny.Mutiny$Session.createQuery(String)\" because \"em\" is null\r\n\tat io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.common.runtime.CommonPanacheQueryImpl.createBaseQuery(CommonPanacheQueryImpl.java:307)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.common.runtime.CommonPanacheQueryImpl.createQuery(CommonPanacheQueryImpl.java:255)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.common.runtime.CommonPanacheQueryImpl.lambda$list$6(CommonPanacheQueryImpl.java:221)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualFunction.apply(SlowContextualFunction.java:21)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:68)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:57)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem$KnownItemSubscription.forward(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:38)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem$KnownItemSubscription.access$100(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:26)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem.subscribe(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:23)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni.subscribe(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:25)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.converters.uni.UniToMultiPublisher$UniToMultiSubscription.request(UniToMultiPublisher.java:58)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.multi.MultiFlatMapOp$FlatMapMainSubscriber.onSubscribe(MultiFlatMapOp.java:163)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.converters.uni.UniToMultiPublisher.subscribe(UniToMultiPublisher.java:26)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.MultiCreate$1.subscribe(MultiCreate.java:156)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.multi.MultiFlatMapOp.subscribe(MultiFlatMapOp.java:56)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.MultiSubscribe.withSubscriber(MultiSubscribe.java:69)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.multi.MultiSelectWhereOp.subscribe(MultiSelectWhereOp.java:30)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractMulti.subscribe(AbstractMulti.java:40)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.multi.MultiFlatMapOp.subscribe(MultiFlatMapOp.java:56)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractMulti.subscribe(AbstractMulti.java:40)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromPublisher$PublisherSubscriber.forward(UniCreateFromPublisher.java:42)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromPublisher$PublisherSubscriber.access$100(UniCreateFromPublisher.java:30)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromPublisher.subscribe(UniCreateFromPublisher.java:26)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform.subscribe(UniOnItemTransform.java:22)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform.subscribe(UniOnItemTransform.java:22)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni.subscribe(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:25)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform.subscribe(UniOnItemTransform.java:22)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform.subscribe(UniOnItemTransform.java:22)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.withSubscriber(UniSubscribe.java:50)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.with(UniSubscribe.java:90)\r\n\tat org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.UniResponseHandler.handle(UniResponseHandler.java:17)\r\n\tat org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.UniResponseHandler.handle(UniResponseHandler.java:8)\r\n\tat org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:141)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.execute(EventLoopContext.java:81)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.execute(ContextImpl.java:260)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.execute(EventLoopContext.java:22)\r\n\tat org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.VertxResteasyReactiveRequestContext$1.execute(VertxResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:69)\r\n\tat org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.resume(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:82)\r\n\tat org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.resume(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:50)\r\n\tat org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InputHandler$InputListener.done(InputHandler.java:84)\r\n\tat org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.VertxResteasyReactiveRequestContext$5.handle(VertxResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:260)\r\n\tat org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.VertxResteasyReactiveRequestContext$5.handle(VertxResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:254)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:100)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:63)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpEventHandler.handleEnd(HttpEventHandler.java:76)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest.onEnd(Http1xServerRequest.java:565)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest.lambda$pendingQueue$1(Http1xServerRequest.java:127)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.streams.impl.InboundBuffer.handleEvent(InboundBuffer.java:240)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.streams.impl.InboundBuffer.write(InboundBuffer.java:130)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest.handleEnd(Http1xServerRequest.java:546)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.execute(EventLoopContext.java:71)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.DuplicatedContext.execute(DuplicatedContext.java:163)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.onEnd(Http1xServerConnection.java:189)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.onContent(Http1xServerConnection.java:179)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.handleOther(Http1xServerConnection.java:159)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.handleMessage(Http1xServerConnection.java:147)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.read(ConnectionBase.java:155)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:154)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)\r\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.channelRead(WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.java:99)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)\r\n\tat io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)\r\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)\r\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xOrH2CHandler.end(Http1xOrH2CHandler.java:61)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xOrH2CHandler.channelRead(Http1xOrH2CHandler.java:38)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)\r\n\tat io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)\r\n\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)\r\n\tat io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)\r\n\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)"
} ==> expected: <200> but was: <500>
    at my.project.customer.conrtoller.CustomerControllerTest.testBasicCreation(CustomerControllerTest.java:35)
```

Comment: What version of Quarkus are you using?

Comment: quarkus v 2.2.2.final

Comment: Can you try with `2.3.0.CR1`?

Comment: tried upgrading to 2.3.0.CR1 and getting a buildexception (log in main question)

Comment: You need to make sure you have updated all instances of the Quarkus version in the pom.xml

Comment: my bad, the build wasn't completely carried forward. Updated the question to include both errors and depdendency list.

Comment: First of all, there is no reason to switch to a named datasource. Second, there is no reactive driver for h2, so what you are trying won't work.

Comment: What is a possible option in that case to not have a database required when runnign tests in CI/CD ?

Comment: You would have to use Maven profiles which would result in the inclusion of different quarkus dependencies.

Comment: The PanacheRepository  in use is only present in the reactive dependency however no? Or do you mean having the repositories in separate projects completely and included with profiles?

Comment: Ah good point. As there is no reactive driver for h2, what I mentioned won't work

Comment: Curious at this point, Is this planned at all or is there a reason it's not there?  Since I saw r2dbc implementations for h2 already, even though they aren't ideal at least they allow people to work. https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-h2

Comment: It should likely not be too difficult - just a matter of priorities. Can you open an issue on the Quarkus repository asking for that?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this answer, this is not possible using quarkus. A feature request has been opened here:
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/20471